# Sum two dataframe with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sum two dataframe but I lose some data in the output. All the data in the first level of the multiindex `29193` are gone.

Input `ext_bal`:

```
                          2019-10-23    2019-10-24
app_vendor_id currency                            
3             DASH      0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
              ETC       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
              XRP       1.102733e+06  1.102733e+06
29193         BCH       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
              BSV       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
              BTC       4.991005e+00  4.991005e+00
              BTG       4.990997e+00  4.990997e+00
              DASH      0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
              ENJ       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
              ETC       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
              ETH       3.017995e+01  3.017995e+01
```

Input `ext_bal_ex`:

```
created_at              2019-10-23 00:00:00  2019-10-24 00:00:00
app_vendor_id currency                                          
 3             DASH               200.000000           200.000000
               ETC               2000.000000          2000.000000
               XRP              18900.000000         18900.000000
```

output:

```
                         2019-10-23    2019-10-24
app_vendor_id currency                           
 3             DASH      2.000000e+02  2.000000e+02
               ETC       2.000000e+03  2.000000e+03
               XRP       1.121633e+06  1.121633e+06
 29193         BCH       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
               BSV       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
               BTC       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
               BTG       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
               DASH      0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
               ENJ       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
               ETC       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
               ETH       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```

To sum the two dataframe I did:

```
ext_bal = (ext_bal + ext_bal_ex).fillna(0)
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do

```
ext_bal.add(ext_bal_ex,fill_value=0)
```

Comment: thanks it works. I tried pd.sum before but it did not work. Do I need to conclude that pd.add is always better than pd.sum?

Comment: @mamadede seems like that is more fit your case